# generate public key from pk8 file

Tags: openssl, public-key-encryption

I have a pk8 file with private key (ecc256) , I need to get the public key.
I tried to look over the web, and i found some openssl forums discussing pem files
I didnt find about pk8

Answer (score 2):

found a way:
first convert .pk8 to pem :

```
openssl pkcs8 -in keys.pk8 -inform DER  -out prv.pem
```

then, convert prv.pem to pub.pem:

```
openssl ec -in prv.pem -pubout -out pub.pem
```